# A fast way to duplicate a website (Wordpress) on my Nginx server environment?

Tags: scripting

What is the fastest way to duplicate one of my own websites (Wordpress) which currently sits on my Nginx server environment on my VPS, for testing purposes? Is there a script or a utility that will make it automatically?

Say, the full url is:

```
https://111.111.111.111/example.com || `example.com`.
```

and the utility will duplicate the site as to:

`https://111.111.111.111/test`

The website is a simple Wordpress website with 30 pages and 5 basic plugins. No customizations anywhere (system or Wordpress).

Comment: Likely there is no fast way. It could be developed, but it would be a big work and it is a rare problem.

Comment: Dear @peterh please see my updated question with a code I tried to write for this task and its readme file.

Comment: You forgot to mention, that you *have* access to the file structure and to the database of the site. Your question looks like if you would want to duplicate a site to which you don't have any access. Exactly this ignorance is what drives many answerers total crazy here.

Comment: Btw, the script is good. Well-written. You are good in the command line. :-)

Comment: Hmm, sorry not to mention this clearly (I've now edited) and so much thanks!

Comment: Reopened the question. You can post the script as an answer now, instead of editing it into the question

Comment: If you answer your own question, you don't get rep for that directly, but self-answered questions tend to be popular between the voters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not fast, but the following code describes the approach I took. Copy paste to test, and if worked, run as one piece by putting the code in a block:

```
(
    The code...
)
```

### The code

```
cd /var/www/html/
echo "1/3: Please enter the domain of the site you want to duplicate into a subdomain test version." && read domain
echo "2/3: Please enter the password for your Mysql root user." && read -s rps
echo "3/3: Please enter the password of the site's DB user." && read -s sps
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep -Po "inet addr:\K[^\s]+" | grep -v "^127")

rm -rf ./test/ ./test.sql
cp -r ./${domain} ./test/
sed -i "s/${domain}/test"/g ./test/wp-config.php
cp -r /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf
sed -i "s/${domain}/test"/g /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf

echo "DROP USER IF EXISTS 'test'@'localhost';" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}"
echo "DROP database IF EXISTS test;" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}"
echo "CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY \"${sps}\";" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}"
echo "CREATE database test;" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}"
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}"
mysql -u root -p"${rps}" -e "SELECT user FROM mysql.user; SHOW grants FOR "test'@'localhost"; show databases;"

mysqldump -u root -p"${rps}" "${domain}" > test.sql
mysql -u test -p"${sps}" test < ./test.sql

cd test
wp search-replace "https://${domain}" "http://test.${ipa}/test" --allow-root
# Note that https:// && http:// are needed to apply a URL rewrite rule.

cat <<-TESTCONF > /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.${domain}.conf
    server {
        root /var/www/html/test/;
        server_name ${ipa} test.${domain};

        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
            try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        listen 80;
    }
TESTCONF

unset domain rps sps ipa
```